# What does "BS warning" mean?

Tags: warnings, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, suppress-warnings

In a recent [mail](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2013-08/msg00461.html), I saw a phrase "BS warning".  Although this mail is in Emacs's mailing list, I don't think this phrase it's Emacs-specific.

I've searched the web, but didn't get anything that looked relevant.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it's a technical term, he's just using it with its normal, English meaning.

Comment: Question is off-topic. It's not a technical term: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=BS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the context of the linked email, it means the the warnings are not real, that they can (and should) be disregarded.